# Power BI "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am trying to leverage a percentage column [percent] to filter the output of the column [throughput]. The DAX query for my measure returns:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was
> expected.

The query looks like:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE('table'[throughput],FILTER(ALL('table'[percent]),'table'[percent] > 0.94 && 'table'[percent] < 0.96)))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the expression for `FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE` as well as the filter criteria for the `CALCULATE` function.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE('table'[throughput],0),FILTER(ALL('table'[percent]),'table'[percent] > 0.94 && 'table'[percent] < 0.96))
```

`FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE` is a [Time Intelligence function](https://dax.guide/firstnonblankvalue/), so the first parameter is typically a date table, and the second is a measure that you will return.  However, by supplying a column and then "0" as the second parameter you can get your desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately the query only returns "0" now.

Comment: @convexrickiez I am using Excel so I don't have FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE.  I tested using FIRSTNONBLANK instead, perhaps that would work for you as well.